# Cisco mds zoning

Tags: cisco, storage-area-network, switch

I am in the process of setting up an MDS fabric swicth and was wondering what the recommended best practice is for zoning? Is is single target single initiator based or single initiator multiple targets?. Our SAN array controller has 8 storgae ports attached to the fabric switch and i would like to know what implications grouping these ports togther as a single group alias would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a two-member-zone man myself, i.e. server and storage, though sometimes I have two or more storage ports if I anticipate a lot of activity. There's really no issue with having more storage ports but you do increase the number of paths, hopefully your OS and/or multipathing-software will handle that for you - I use ESX and Windows-with-Vertitas-Storage-Foundation and they both work just great. Best of luck.